# Verilog counting problem - posedge detector with if statement not working as expected

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog

First I am doing **reset** with **reset input**. Then I check the led position by turning on pinA. Next, a **shift** posedge to switch to the next led but the counting not going to its next led.

After doing reset from "00" it goes to "10" or "11" on shift posedge. But as I am adding just 1 so that should have gone to "01"

Where am I going wrong?

```
module syScore(
    input clk,
    input shift,
    input enb,
    input reset,
    input pinA,
    input pinB,
    input pinC,
    input pinD,
    input pinE,
    output reg out1,
    output reg out2,
    output reg out3,
    output reg out4,
    output reg out5,
    output reg out6,
    output reg out7,
    output statusBit
);

reg [1:0] enPosition;
reg out;
wire w1,w2;
wire w3,w4;
reg j;

always @ (posedge clk) begin
        // posedge detector block with if statement
        if (j == 0 && shift == 1) begin
            j<=1;
            enPosition <= enPosition + 2'b01;
            out3 <= 1;
        end
        if (shift == 0) begin
            j<=0;
            out3 <= 0;
        end
        if (reset == 1) begin
            enPosition <= 2'b00;
            out1 <= 0;
            out2 <= 0;
            out3 <= 0;
            out4 <= 1;
            out6 <= 0;
            out7 <= 0;
            j <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            out4 <= 0;
        end
        case(enPosition)
            2'b00: out1 <= statusBit;
            2'b01: out2 <= statusBit;
            2'b10: out6 <= statusBit;
            2'b11: out7 <= statusBit;
            default: out5 <= statusBit;
        endcase
end

assign statusBit = pinA;

endmodule
```

Comment: I don't really understand the intent here. If you're targeting an FPGA, why don't you either oversample the signal using an existing clock, or (if it's going to a GCLK pin and is suitably debounced and conditioned) just use it as a clock directly?

Comment: Because there is no clock in your design to 'count' and 'shift'.

Comment: If I use "always @ (posedge clk)" then also the counting not working properly. After doing reset from "00" it goes to "10" or "11" on shift posedge. But as I am adding just 1 so that should have gone to "01"

Comment: The circuit NEEDS clock regardless of what happened when you used clock. That's secondary.  Update you question with details/code.

Comment: Hi @MituRaj, I explained the question and code.

Comment: `"I check the led position by turning on pinA."` Where are you doing that?

Comment: pinA is connected with a switch on the FPGA board. The switch status is directly coupled with led status, so by toggling the switch I was checking the position.

Comment: Are you trying to detect a positive edge on the `shift` input when `j` is zero? Where does `shift`come from? Is it debounced?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what each signals are on your code. It is not clear what is the end-objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having difficulty understanding your intent, but I think you are trying to detect a positive edge on the `shift` input, and then use that edge to increment a counter. The counter is then used to connect the `statusBit` input to different outputs, i.e. `out7`, `out6`, `out2`, `out1`.

Firstly, you need a clear demarcation between the reset condition and normal operation:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (reset == 1)
    begin
        // Do reset condition.
    end
    else
    begin
        // Do normal operation.
    end
end
```

Secondly, you need a to detect the positive edge on `shift`. If `shift` is coming from an external button or switch, it needs to be debounced. The positive edge detector could be implemented like this:

```
// Positive edge detection of shift input.
assign shift_posedge = (shift == 1) & (shift_previous == 0);
```

...where `shift_previous` is a single bit register that is assigned the value of `shift` every clock cycle in "normal operation" in the above `always` block:

```
shift_previous <= shift;
```

Lastly, you need to decode the counter value to connect the `statusBit` input to the correct output, and zero the other outputs:

```
always @*
begin
    case (enPosition)
        2'b00: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, statusBit};
        2'b01: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { 1'b0, 1'b0, statusBit, 1'b0};
        2'b10: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { 1'b0, statusBit, 1'b0, 1'b0};
        2'b11: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { statusBit, 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0};
        default: out5 = statusBit;  // Indicate invalid enPosition.
    endcase
end
```

Putting it all together it could look something like the following code just to give you the general idea. In response to comments, I've removed the multiple drivers and changed the assignments in the synchronous reset block to non-blocking. As an alternative for synchronous and registered outputs, the `case` statement that decodes the `enPosition` counter could be moved to the *normal operation* block and the multiple drivers uncommented in the *synchronous reset* block:

```
module syCore
(
    input reset,
    input clk,
    input shift,        // Debounced signal from switch or button.
    input statusBit,
    output reg out1,
    output reg out2,
    output reg out3,
    output reg out4,
    output reg out5,
    output reg out6,
    output reg out7,
    output reg out8
);

    reg shift_previous;
    wire shift_posedge;

    reg [1:0] enPosition;

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (reset == 1)
        begin
            //
            // Synchronous reset.
            //
            
            shift_previous <= shift;
            enPosition <= 2'b00;
            //out1 <= 0;  // Removed multiple driver.
            //out2 <= 0;  // Removed multiple driver.
            out3 <= 0;
            out4 <= 1;  // Indicate reset condition.
            out5 <= 0;
            //out6 <= 0;  // Removed multiple driver.
            //out7 <= 0;  // Removed multiple driver.
            out8 <= 0;
        end
        else
        begin
            //
            // Normal operation.
            //
            
            out4 <= 0;  // Indicate normal operation.

            if (shift_posedge)
            begin
                // Indicate positive edge on shift.
                // Will go high for one clock cycle.
                out3 <= 1;

                // Increment counter.
                enPosition <= enPosition + 2'b01;
            end
            else
            begin
                out3 <= 0;  // Indicate level voltage on shift.
            end

            shift_previous <= shift;
        end
    end

    // Positive edge detection of shift input.
    assign shift_posedge = (shift == 1) & (shift_previous == 0);

    always @*
    begin
        // Decode the counter and connect statusBit to the correct output.
        case (enPosition)
            2'b00: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, statusBit};
            2'b01: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { 1'b0, 1'b0, statusBit, 1'b0};
            2'b10: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { 1'b0, statusBit, 1'b0, 1'b0};
            2'b11: {out7, out6, out2, out1 } = { statusBit, 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0};
            default: out5 = statusBit;  // Indicate invalid enPosition.
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```

[image: Simulation]

*Figure 1 – Simulation waveforms*

[image: RTL Synthesis]

*Figure 2 – RTL synthesis schematic*

Comment: Hi tim, Thank you so much for this explanation. How to fix "connected to multiple drivers problem" do you know?  It is showing "Multi-source in Unit <syScore> on signal <out5>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.". I already faced this problem before.

Comment: You have multiple drivers at all out signals @tim

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that. When I synthesised it in Quartus, it found multiple drivers on `out1`, `out2`, `out6` and `out7`. When I removed them, it synthesised ok.

Comment: And inside the synchronous reset block,  non-blocking assignments are recommended.

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompilers:246 - "core.v" line 67 Reference to scalar reg 'shift_posedge' is not a legal net lvalue. `assign shift_posedge = (shift == 1) & (shift_previous == 0);`. When I change "shift_posedge" to "wire" type then it is running. But for "reg" type the error is thrown. I am using Xilinx ISE.

Comment: Thanks @DipnarayanDas. I've changed it to `wire` now. Don't forget to accept it as the answer if it answers your question.